# mysql client changes IP

Tags: mysql, tcp, client

several of client boxes changed their IPs and now those boxes can not access the database. at best the connection is on and off  (mostly off). other boxes which do not have their IPs changed can access the db fine. btw, I have troubleshoot from networking side and found no issue. I have been told/heard that mysql db maintain somekind of ip-hostname tables/lookup table? could this be the problem . how to solve this?

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)
   at MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
```

Comment: Do you have access to the actual MySQL error message? What troubleshooting have you done from the network side (have you verified your port is open the the range of IP's you are expecting)?  Can you add information on you mysql user configuration (i.e. allowable hosts)?

Comment: 130725 19:51:28 [Warning] IP address 'xx' could not be resolved: No such host is known. 
130823 16:26:30 [Warning] IP address 'xx' could not be resolved: No such host is known.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the users that you are using have the "Limit Conectivity to Host Matching" option configured in the MysqlWorkbench

Comment: I am using root. root there are 2 root users , first has localhost and second has % as Limit Connectivity to Hosts Matching

Comment: default installation root user has either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' ip limitations; unless you have changed that conf.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL identifies user accounts by combination of username and hostname. The hostname can be domain name or IP address. The hostname can be wildcarded. See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/account-names.html).

User accounts are stored in the system `mysql` database, table `user`. You can manipulate it directly, on you can use [`GRANT` SQL statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/grant.html) to grant access for your new IP addresses, for example:

```
GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'myusername'@'123.45.67.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xyz';
```

This will grant all privileges on all tables of “mydatabase” database to users connecting from any IP address starting with “123.45.67.” with username “myusername” and password “xyz”.

You might need to issue `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` SQL statement after modifying user accounts.

Comment: all clients are using root as user. do I still to do this?

Comment: Please check output of `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user` statement.

Comment: 4 rows: 1) blank, % 2) root, % 3) blank, localhost 4) root, localhost